# Can not fully remove Fabric & Crashlytics

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, crashlytics, xcode10

Trying to remove **fabric** from an IOS project I'm working on. I have removed it from the pod file(s) and did a pod install. (When saying fabric onwards I mean both fabric and crashlytics)

I have removed any references to Fabric in the code by searching the project with  cmd+shift+f. And clean the build folder.

Then when building I get the following error:

> /Users/just_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheApp-epakvsyxjlzjjfclvjqwrljowaio/Build/Intermediates.noindex/TheAppMobile.build/Debug-iphoneos/TheAppMobile.build/Script-CF862497221C49250071D547.sh: line 2: /Users/just_user/Projects/TheApp/app/TheAppMobile/../Pods/Fabric/run: No such file or directory
>   Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

So obviously some reference left somewhere.

So I used Finder to search the project for any references to Fabric which resulted in a lot of references still there not visible via Xcode. I removed all of those references too.

Then cleaned cache of cocoapods, re-installed the pods again. Cleaned build folder and the result is the same as the error above.

Then I deleted the `"Users/just_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheApp-epakvsyxjlzjjfclvjqwrljowaio/"` folder and cleaned and build everything again. Nope, error still there.

What else could it be which isn't visible through xcode and finder searches that keeps a reference to Fabric?

Comment: Did you check the setting in Build Phase?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the error, it seems you forgot to remove Run script phase for Fabric under Build phases for your target:

[image]